# Mysql table best practice for replacing needing nulls as primary key

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table named "Event_places" with primary keys shown below. In all cases, event_id,dog_id, and score_type_id are necessary. However, in some scoring types, there is no waitlist_type_id and there is a round, or there is no round and there is a waitlist_type_id. In all of these cases, there is only one record per the keys that I do need to specify.

My question is: what is the best practice for making this work so that there are no conflicts with keys, as each scenario seems to require a different set of primary keys?**

I've considered:
*Making multiple tables*: this doesn't seem best because if this same scenario happens with N columns, you have N^2 required tables.
*Using -1 to indicate it doesn't exist*: this doesn't seem best since this would require making entries because each column references a foreign key, and this would not prevent duplicates.
*Creating a unique id for every entry*: this also does not prevent duplicates

[image]

Comment: So the first 3 columns are always unique? Then just make those 3 columns the primary key, and the other columns are not part of the PK.

Comment: And allow NULLs in the optional columns.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to specify that at least one of `waitlist_type_id` or `round` must be non-null? You can do that with a `CHECK` constraint. `CONSTRAINT CHECK NOT (waitlist_type_id IS NULL AND round IS NULL)`

Comment: @Barmar That's what I have done before, but to give you a counter example, I may need two entries 1: event_id = 5,dog_id = 7, score_type_id = "id_2" waitlist_type_id IS NULL, round =1 2: event_id = 5,dog_id = 7, score_type_id = "id_2" waitlist_type_id IS NULL, round =2. This would cause a duplicate pk error.

Comment: You can't use this as the primary key. Just make it a UNIQUE KEY, it doesn't have a restriction on NULL values. If you want a primary key, add an auto_increment ID column.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table Event_places;` and `select version();`

Comment: are there scoring types where there is both round and waitlist_type_id?  if so, do you need to allow the same round (and the other three fields) but different waitlist type ids, or the same waitlist type id but different rounds?

Comment: @Barmar if any of the columns in a unique key are null, duplicates will be allowed.  this is likely not what they want.